# List Validation in kendo spreadsheet validation where values are defined in array

Tags: validation

I have a kendo spreadsheet which I have implemented validation for third column

```
 <script>
    var spreadsheet = $("#spreadsheet").kendoSpreadsheet({
      toolbar: false,
      sheets: [
        {
          rows: [
            {
              cells: [
                { value: "Id" },
                { value: "Name" },
                { value: "IsActive" }               
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
                name: "ListValues",
                rows: [ 
                    {
                        cells: [
                            {
                                value: true
                            },
                            {
                                value: false
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }

       ]                   
    }).data("kendoSpreadsheet");

    var range = spreadsheet.activeSheet().range("1:1");
    range.enable(false);
    var columnSens = spreadsheet.activeSheet().range("C2:C30");
    columnSens.validation({
      dataType: "list",
      from: "ListValues!A$1:B$1",
      allowNulls: true,
      type: "reject",
      titleTemplate: "Value Invalid",
      messageTemplate: "Valid Values: 'true' or 'false'."
    });
</script>
```

I want to know is there any way to perform validation by declaring an array like

```
  var ListOfValues = [true,false];
```

and the calling the array in "from:" section, like :-

```
    columnSens.validation({
      dataType: "list",
      from: "ListOfValues",
      allowNulls: true,
      type: "reject",
      titleTemplate: "Value Invalid",
      messageTemplate: "Valid Values: 'true' or 'false'."
    });
```

Please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

To use an array for mapping to from property, simply serialize the array and replace '[' and ']' characters to '{' and '}' respectively.

```
var arr = ["name", "age", "whatever"];
```

the value for the from property would then be assigned like this:

```
{
   from: JSON.stringify(arr).replace('[', '{').replace(']', '}')
}
```